# jquery ajax complete function firing immediately

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a strange situation I have never seen before. I have a jquery ajax that calls a method that does a sql query, builds the json response and write its back out to the response stream.

As soon as the ajax call is  executed the complete function fires as a success with a null response text.... I can debug the method and see that is it is building the response and returning it. Just not sure here any ideas? ASP .net if that helps.

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'Data/ServiceCalls.aspx?SelectRequestsWithDate=1&start_date=' + escape(jQuery("#request_start_date").val()) + '&end_date=' + escape(jQuery("#request_end_date").val()) + "'",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonresponse, stat) {


                if (stat === "success") {
                    var thegrid = jQuery("#grid_requests")[0];
                    var jsonObject = eval('(' + jsonresponse.responseText + ')');
                    thegrid.addJSONData(jsonObject);
                    jsonresponse = null;
                    thegrid = null;
                }
            }


        });
```

Comment: With that URL... it looks like it should be a `GET`... not sure if that would cause it.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The call is still getting the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using POST, you could try sending data as POST values instead of as GET appending it to your url, like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'Data/ServiceCalls.aspx",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data : {"SelectRequestsWithDate" : 1"...},
   ......
```

Or try using GET as your type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug, jus move the sucess callback function to a separate one:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'Data/ServiceCalls.aspx?SelectRequestsWithDate=1&start_date=' + escape(jQuery("#request_start_date").val()) + '&end_date=' + escape(jQuery("#request_end_date").val()) + "'",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: callback
        });

function callback (jsonresponse, stat) {


                if (stat === "success") {
                    var thegrid = jQuery("#grid_requests")[0];
                    var jsonObject = eval('(' + jsonresponse.responseText + ')');
                    thegrid.addJSONData(jsonObject);
                    jsonresponse = null;
                    thegrid = null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys. I am about to get back to work on it. Sure my head will be a little bit clearer this morning

Answer (score 0):

I thankyou for all your suggestions. Issue seems to be that I had the ajax call inside of jqgrid. For whatever reason it was making the success function fire immediately. I moved it outside the grid and everything started working.

Not the best answer but maybe it will help someone else.

Blake